# What is the relationship between the chords in the bridge of Frank Ocean's Sweet Life?

Tags: chords, harmony, chord-progressions, analysis

The chords in the bridge to Frank Ocean's Sweet Life are:

*||: C#maj9 | C#m7 | Bmaj7 | A#m7 :||*

Here's a link to a tutorial of the song that shows the chords:

And a link to the song (bridge at 3:03):

I am finding it hard to understand how these chords are related and what key this bridge is in? The rest of the song seems to be in Emaj. But these chords stand out like a sore thumb - yet somehow sound so good. How is that possible? Do they have share a relationship in the circle of fifths?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One thing to keep in mind is many pop music composers do not write with the idea of being able to justify their chord progressions with tonal harmony analysis. Sometimes they just hit a certain sequence they like and go with it.

That being said, in this case both the verse and the bridge of this song make use of a device that has been used in several American songbook standards, major 7th chords going down stepwise with a transitional chord or chords in between. “How High the Moon”, “Midnight Sun” and the bridge of “Watch What Happens” all use this chord progression:

Gmaj7 |////|Gm7 |C7 |Fmaj7 |////| etc.

The verses and bridge both have this same sequence in different keys with a subtle difference, they use only one transitional chord instead of a ii-V. In the verses it is a V7sus4 (B7sus4) to the Emaj7 and in the bridge it is a iim7 (C#m7) to the Bmaj7. In essence it is almost the same chord because you can think of a B7sus4 like a F#m7/B.

The A#m7 is more in line with what I said in my first paragraph, just something that sounded and felt good to the composer. You can call it the relative minor of C#maj7. I don’t hear it as being very functional, it just sounds good.

Another interesting thing to point out is the bridge is a modulation to the dominant (F# and E to C# and B) which is a very common modulation in classical music.

Comment: That A#m7 translates to C#6, so could be construed as such, albeit with a different root. Not sure if Lover falls into the same category  - it's too early here!

Comment: @Tim I did make a similar connection by saying it could be the relative minor of C#. “Lover” is more descending chromatics if I recall...

Comment: This is awesome, thanks for the explanation. I see the similarity now between the F#m7/B in the verse and the C#m7 in the bridge. In that way it's kind of like almost the same exact passing chord from the verse just in the modulated key of B. So you can impute the F# and C#m7/F# becomes F#7sus4. Aha! Like a ii-V-I. And yeah I guess the  A#m7 just sounds good (being the relative minor of C# probably doesn't hurt). Now I'm overthinking it maybe, but your explanation makes a lot of sense. Thank you!

Comment: That’s right, ii and Vsus are very similar. it also occurred to me that the whole tune is sort of a ii-V-I except with a IImaj7 instead of a iim7!

Answer (score 3):

**What key is the bridge?**

The bridge modulates; it's not in a single key. For a similar kind of chord motion (similar, but not identical), see the verse of [Green Dolphin Street](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=8wwxaJ80nCg).

**[It] sound[s] so good. How is that possible?**

The bridge chords are, in effect, a transposition of the chords on the verse, plus C# is a closely enough related key to E, so the ear doesn't have to make too radical an adjustment with the first chord. (C# minor is the relative minor to E major; and C# major is just a hop, skip, and a jump from C# minor.)

**Do they have share a relationship in the circle of fifths?**

Not really. The C#maj9 to C#min7 is just a major-minor transition, so no circle of fifths needed. The other two chords are best seen as direct modulations. It all works by making use of step-wise motion and common-tones. To try to analyze them in terms of common  practice Tonal harmony rules would be misleading.

In general, jazz and popular music make use of common practice voice-leading principles (such as step-wise motion), but much less strictly (such as in the resolution [or even definition] of dissonances) than the music Tonality was developed to describe.